# list index out of range in for loop (2nd iteration)

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, split

In my programm I take some data (variable raw) out of a database and have to use it.
When using `print(raw)` this gets displayed: `('x1 y1 z1 \nx2 y2 z2 \nx3 y3 z3 \nx4 y4 z4',)`
(raw has over 450 elements so I shortened it)

Now I have to get `x1` and `y1` and forward them to another module. To do this I first split up `raw`

```
 pass_str = str(raw).split(f'\\n')
 print(pass_str)
```

The printed result was the following: `["('x1 y1 z1 ", 'x2 y2 z2', 'x3 y3 z3', 'x4 y4 z4',)"]`

To get the single parameters I used a for-loop so I can first get `x1, y1` and then `x2, y2` and so on:

```
 for i in range(len(pass_str)):
  pass_data = pass_str[i].split()
  el = pass_data[0].split("'", 1)[1]  
  az = pass_data[1]
  task = 'P' + ' ' + az + ' ' + el
  client.send_request(task)
```

The first iteration of the for-loop works without any problems. In the second iteration the for-loop stops after `pass_data = pass_str[i].split()`

The problem seems to occure in the line for "el = ...", where I get the error

> Error: list index out of range

Comment: It looks like it's a list containing a single string.. so it only have one element. Also, please fix the indentation in your question,  obviously that can make a big difference!

Comment: Always make questions reproducible for answerers. Limit the data your testing to the minimal set that can reproduce the issue and add that content to your post. Without being able to reproduce this, you're only going to get speculative answers.

Comment: I tried printing the variable pass_data and this was displayed correct in the 2nd iteration, so there should be a second element. (1st Iteration: pass_data = x1 y1 z1, 2nd Iteration: pass_data = x2 y2 z2.

Comment: It is obvious that you are making an unwarranted assumption about the length of `pass_data[0].split("'", 1)`. Either look before you leap and first verify that assumption, or use error trapping to handle it when it is violated. Without a [mcve] it is hard to say any more than that. Your comment doesn't add any clarity `"x2 y2 z2".split("'", 1)` is a list of length 1, so why do you think it has a second element? Perhaps you meant `.split("",1)`?

Comment: You're converting a string to a list this gives you a string representation of a list, including all the braces etc... then splitting that.  I really don't think that's what you want to be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the string representation of a list, then parse that to extract some meaningful data.  The string representation of a list is not a very useful data structure to try and work with!  Whereas a list itself is.

```
raw =  [('x1 y1 z1 \\nx3 y2 z1',)]
pass_str = str(raw).split(f'\\n') # ["[('x1 y1 z1 \\", "x3 y2 z1',)]"]
```

You should be converting the string into a list, and accessing it properly.

```
raw =  [('x1 y1 z1 \\nx3 y2 z1',)]
pass_strings = raw[0][0].split('\\n') #["x1 y1 z1","x3 y2 z1"]

for pass_string in pass_strings:
    pass_data = pass_string.split() #['x1','y1','z1']

    el = pass_data[0]
    az = pass_data[1]
    task = 'P' + ' ' + az + ' ' + el
    print(task) #> P x1 y1
```

Comment: I upvoted this as soon as I read the first few sentences of your answer. In effect, OP 's question is a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/357835), and you are answering the question that they should have asked rather than the question that they asked.